# Complex ActiveRecord query with many joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm creating some form to filter my users, table `User` and I'm discovering the joys of ActiveRecord.

- `User` has `name` and `function` columns.
- `User` has many `Address`
- `Address` has `country` and `town` columns.
- `User` has many `Hobby`
- `Hobby` has a `category` column.

In my params I have `name`, `function`, `country`,  `town` and `category`.

I basically want to get all Users who match at least one of these params (`OR` condition, I use a MySQL database).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered a text search engine, like Sphinx or Solr (based on Lucene)?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, would be overkill though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy some code below to let you see what I expected.

The query is built with `OR` and empty `params` are not included (neither their values, nor the join).

```
def self.filtering(name, country, category)
  query, join_array, query_string = self, [], []
  unless name.blank?
    query_string << " users.name = :name"
  end
  unless country.blank?
    query_string << "addresses.country = :country"
    join_array << :addresses
  end
  unless category.blank?
    query_string << "hobbies.category = :category"
    join_array << :hobbies
  end

  join_array.each do |q|
    query = query.joins(q)
  end

  q.where(query_string * " OR ", :name => name, :country => country, :category => category)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head, I think this will do it:

```
q = params[:query]

User.all(
  :conditions => ["
    users.name like ? or 
    users.function like ? or
    addresses.country like ? or
    addresses.town like ? or
    hobbies.category like ?
  ", q, q, q, q, q],
  :joins => [:hobbies, {:addresses => :country}]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it gave me a bit of inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you need to search across multiple tables you are better off denormalizing your data in an index. I had to do this over a year ago and chose to use a combination of [Sunspot](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/) and [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and this worked really well for me.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation but this would be overkill for what I am looking for. BTW, I've got a solution which suits.